# What testing we can do to verify correctness, after we remove androidx.startup.InitializationProvider after upgrading to WorkManager 2.7.1?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

We just upgraded from

```
def work_version = "2.4.0"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
implementation "androidx.work:work-gcm:$work_version"
```

to

```
def work_version = "2.7.1"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
implementation "androidx.work:work-gcm:$work_version"
```

---

Based on https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration

We changed our `AndroidManifest.xml`, from

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
        tools:node="remove">
    </provider>
```

to

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove">
    </provider>
```

---

If there any testing we can do, to confirm our `AndroidManifest.xml` change is correct? Because, we execute some simple WorkManager foreground task when the app is quit. We find the task both run success, before & after the `AndroidManifest.xml` change.

We expect if we are using incorrect code snippet in `AndroidManifest.xml`, we can have early detection like

1. App crash
2. The worker task doesn't run

But it doesn't happen such.

When I run code analysis, I am getting warning

> Remove androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer from your
> AndroidManifest.xml when using on-demand initialization.

Is it a concern?